# OpenVPN Community Edition with Post Auth Hardware Address Checking Script

Tags: ubuntu, authentication, vpn, openvpn

I'm trying to set up OpenVPN Community Edition with Post Auth Hardware Address Checking Script, but I can't find out how to do it.

Basically, I'm running Ubuntu Server 20.04 LTS and I was easily able to set up OpenVPN using the following guide https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/ubuntu-20-04-lts-set-up-openvpn-server-in-5-minutes /

Now I would like to set up MAC address checking through the Post Auth script similarly as described for the Access Server here: https://openvpn.net/vpn-server-resources/access-server-post-auth-script-host-checking/

According to edition comparison (https://openvpn.net/open-source-vs-openvpn-access-server/) the Community Edition supports Post Auth scripts so it should be possible.

Does anyone have experience with setting up this feature for the Community Edition of OpenVPN?

Thanks, in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

I have searched a lot of information on how to achive that. Generally found nothing so I have implemented it myself.
Here are the steps you need to do:

```
In client config put this directive: 
push-peer-info

In server config put:

script-security 2
verb 3
client-connect /etc/openvpn/mac-check.py
```

Create file in /etc/openvpn/db.txt -> where you put username and mac address
in the following format:

```
username-M:A:C:A:D:R:E:S:S
john.doe-C4:23:60:FA:CC:1A
```

So now when user connects in the log he/she will trow his/her mac address under
IV_HWADDR=
Writing this mac in db.txt will grant this user only access from that machine.

Do chmod 664 /var/log/openvpn.log in order to give access to script to search though it.

And the script mac-check.py but make sure you have python3.6 in your bin folder or do a symlink in it.

```
 #!/bin/python3.6
    
    import re
    import sys
    
    # vars
    db_file = '/etc/openvpn/db.txt'
    log_file = '/var/log/openvpn.log'
    regex_mac = 'IV_HWADDR=(.*)'
    regex_username = 'username \'(.*)\''
    login = False
    
    # create dict
    logs_username_mac_list = []
    
    # get mac and username from logs
    with open(log_file, 'r') as log:
        lines = log.readlines()
        # read only latest 100 lines
        last_50_lines = lines[-50:]
        # iterate latest 50 lines
        for line in last_50_lines:
    
            # find mac
            match_mac = re.search(regex_mac, line)
            if match_mac:
                log_mac = match_mac.group(1)
                # on match, add it to list
                logs_username_mac_list.append(log_mac)
    
            # find username
            match_username = re.search(regex_username, line)
            if match_username:
                log_username = match_username.group(1)
                # on match, add it to list
                logs_username_mac_list.append(log_username)
    
    
    
    # get username and mac from db
    with open(db_file, 'r') as db:
        for line in db.readlines():
            # split username and password based on '-'
            splitter = line.split('-', 1)
            # 0 index is username, removing newline
            db_username = (splitter[0]).rstrip("\n")
            # 1 index is mac, removing newline
            db_mac = (splitter[1]).rstrip("\n")
            # check if username in collected logs matches what we have in db
            if db_username in logs_username_mac_list:
                # get user index and remove 1
                user_index = logs_username_mac_list.index(db_username) - 1
                mac_index = logs_username_mac_list[user_index]
                # if log mac matches db_mac
                if mac_index == db_mac:
                    login = True
    
    if login:
        sys.exit(0)
    else:
        sys.exit(1)
```